# how to display my query in view codeignitier

Tags: codeigniter

this my controler

```
public function ajax_pasien($Kode)
{
    $data = $this->infokamar->get_by_id1($Kode);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

this my model

```
public function get_by_id1($Kode)
{
    $sql = "select a.norm, b.nama as pasien, b.alamat, c.tanggal, c.tanggal1, f.jumlah, f.biaya from TTKunjungan a inner join TMPasien b on A.norm = b.norm inner join TTKunjunganDetail c on A.Kode = c.kodekunjungan inner join TMTrfTindakan d on c.kodetindakan = d.Kode inner join TMTrfLayanan e on d.kodelayanan = e.Kode left join (select kodett, sum(jumlah) as jumlah, sum(biaya) as biaya from TTKunjunganDetail where kodett is not null group by kodett) f on  c.Kode = F.kodett Where e.kodeklasifikasi = 2 and c.tanggal1 is null and c.kodett is null and c.kodetindakan = '{$Kode}'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return($query->result_array());
}
```

and this my view but nothing show

[image]

Comment: Instead of `echo` try to use `var_dump`. But share some view code here.

Comment: see my answer hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check your queries is by two ways:

**1. Printing the last query** Use below code to print last executed query

```
<?php echo $this>db->last_query() ?>
```

**2. Enable profiler** Make sure your output class is loaded/autoloaded. Just enable profiler in your controller's constructor by adding below code and see the magic after rendering the page

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(true)
```

-Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Send data from controller to your respective view as follows in controller..

```
public function ajax_pasien($Kode)
    {
        $data = $this->infokamar->get_by_id1($Kode);
        //echo json_encode($data);
        $this->load->view('view_name',$data);
    }
```